# Convert lowercase to uppercase and vice-versa c programm

Tags: c, c-strings, function-definition, function-call

I am trying really hard to implement a function that will convert lowercase letters to uppercase letters and vice-versa.

What I don't understand is when I use the code in the main it works when I try to put it in an function it doesn't work. I don't get it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char sentence[100];
int count, ch, i;

void KUlowerL(char *sentence)
{
    printf("%s", sentence); // Test if I get char from sentence. it works ?!?!
    for (i=0;(sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++); /* enters the user sentence to change the case */

    sentence[i] = '\0';
    count = i;
    printf("Der Satz ist: %s", sentence);
    printf("\nDer veränderte Satz ist: ");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ch = islower(sentence[i]) ? toupper(sentence[i]) : tolower(sentence[i]);
        putchar(ch);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: ");
    fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);
    KUlowerL(sentence);
}
```

Comment: You do not tell us in what way the output is not correct. What do you get, what do you expect to get?

Comment: You ask for input of the string twice (once with `fgets` and then again with `getchar`). Is that intented?

Comment: @Gerhardh User is unwittingly typing sentence once, then pressing return. When it appears to be hung, press return a second time. Within function, sentence is truncated to zero length, so it appears to be not working... "But it works in main()!!!" There is no prompt to enter sentence a second time. `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 it is correct that this could be one possible version of "not working". But is it purely based on assumption what the OP might want to do. The OP does not tell us what "it" is that is "working in main".

Comment: Normally `islower` and friends will not work at all for non-English letters.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this `?` operator. The function will change the case of the letter ignoring not letters.

```
ch = toupper((unsigned char)sentence[i]);
```

The below line makes no sense

```
for (i=0;(sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++);
```

You simply need to iterate through the string

```
void KUlowerL(char *sentence)
{
    while(*sentence && *sentence != '\n')
        putchar(toupper((unsigned char)*sentence++));
}

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    printf("Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: ");
    fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);
    printf("\n");
    KUlowerL(sentence);
}
```

---

EDIT:

to swap case

```
void SwapCase(char *sentence)
{
    while(*sentence && *sentence != '\n')
    {
        int c = *sentence;

        if(islower((unsigned char)c)) c = toupper((unsigned char)c);
        else if(isupper((unsigned char)c)) c = tolower((unsigned char)c);
        sentence++;
        putchar(c);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    printf("Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: ");
    fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);
    printf("\n");
    SwapCase(sentence);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WdcKh5TfK

Comment: I don't understand. When I replace ch = islower(sentence[i]) ? toupper(sentence[i]) : tolower(sentence[i]); with your code their is still no output?

Comment: I tried using the new code. When I input TEST in uppercase. IT prints TEST in uppercase. Don't understand how this works.

Comment: Okay, now it works. I needed to change the function from toupper into tolower because this function will convert uppercase letters into lowercase. Now I understand but does this work vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

I note the following:

> ```
> fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);
> ```

... which I then note you're passing to `KUlowerL`, so what's with the `getchar` loop? You already did that work with the `fgets` code, aye?

On the note of `getchar` and `tolower`, those two go together in a way that `fgets` can't relate... You need to cast `char` values to `unsigned char` in passing to `tolower`, where they'll be promoted to `int`, whereas `getchar` returns your character already cast for you, so no cast is necessary providing you keep that return value in an **`int`** form...

Comment: Any idea how I can implement this in an easier way?

Comment: @TheLuckyGuy as if you wouldn't get that impression from my last paragraph... Hintedy hint. I'll leave it an exercise for you to write this code without using any arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not appear to work is that loop with `getchar()` and you not expecting to type the sentence ZWEI MAL!!! You press RETURN and see nothing because the second "sentence" is zero characters long...

Gone over your code and made a few changes...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char sentence[100]; // global. need not be passed around
// other variables declared/defined closer to where they are used.

// main() prints the first input sentence so no need to pass a global variable
void KUlowerL( void )
{
    printf("Bitte gebe deinen Satz noch mal ein: ");
    // that for() loop was alright, but doing the work of a standard library function.
    // Use (proven) library functions when possible.
    // "sizeof" is better than repeating "magic number" of 100
    // The compiler knows the size and sizeof means you can grow or
    // shrink buffer in one place, not two...
    fgets( sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin );

    // measure the length (incl. the '\n'
    int count = strlen( sentence );
    printf("Der Satz hält %d buchstabben: %s", count, sentence );

    printf("\nDer veränderte Satz ist: ");
    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        // 'c' is easier to read than 3 copies of 'sentence[i]'
        char c = sentence[ i ];
        // You want to 'swap' the upper/lower case-ness of each letter
        putchar( islower( c ) ? toupper( c ) : tolower( c ) );
    }
}


int main()
{
    printf("Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: ");
    fgets(sentence, 100, stdin);

    printf("main(): sentence is %s", sentence ); // includes '\n' from fgets()

    KUlowerL();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: Guten morgen
main(): sentence is Guten morgen
Bitte gebe deinen Satz noch mal ein: Schlaff Schoen
Der Satz hõlt 15 buchstabben: Schlaff Schoen
{empty line because buffer contains '\n' too.)
Der verõnderte Satz ist: sCHLAFF sCHOEN
```

Comment: thank's for the code. It's working ofcourse. But I don't understand why it's not working with only one input in the main. Why doesn't it work to use the sentence variable in the lower function? Why do I have to input it again in the function that it works.

Comment: @TheLuckyGuy Your OP: `"when I use the code in the main it works when I try to put it in an function it doesn't work."` My version shows how you COULD input a 'sentence' in either main or the function... or both... If you don't want to type in the Zweite mal, remove both the prompt and the fgets() from the function...

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad idea to use global variables like these

```
char sentence[100];
int count, ch, i;
```

and there is no any need to define them as global.

The function already got a string through its parameter. So rewriting it using calls of `getchar` does not make a sense.

```
void KUlowerL(char *sentence)
{
    printf("%s", sentence); // Test if I get char from sentence. it works ?!?!
    for (i=0;(sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++); /* enters the user sentence to change the case */ 
    //...
```

Also the function does not change the processed string.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
char * KUlowerL( char *sentence )
{
    for ( char *p = sentence; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
        {
            *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
        }
        else
        {
            *p = tolower( ( unsigned char )*p );
        }
    }

    return sentence;
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char sentence[N];

    printf( "Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: " );
    fgets( sentence, N, stdin );

    printf( "%s", KUlowerL(sentence) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> to implement a function that will convert lowercase letters to uppercase letters and vice-versa.

**Improve the case swap function**

- A *string* ends with a *null character*.  A *line* of input ends with a `'\n'`.  Better to create your function to work with a *string* and stop at a *null character* than a `'\n'`
- Iterate through the string once.  It is not necessary to first find the string length and then second convert.  Do both together.
- Remove user I/O code from `KUlowerL()`.  Let calling code read data and print the text.  OP's attempt to read 2 lines of input (once in `main()` and once in `KUlowerL()`) causes trouble.  It can explain the "when I use the code in the main it works when I try to put it in an function it doesn't work."
- `is...(int ch)` and `to...(int ch)` are well defined for values `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` and `EOF`, otherwise if `ch < 0`, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).
- `str...()` functions perform as if access to *strings* was done via `unsigned char *`, even if `char` is *signed*.  This case conversion code should perform likewise.
- `KUlowerL()` is a confusing name for a function that swaps case.
- Return something useful, like the string's beginning.

---

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *TLG_swapcase(char *s) {
  unsigned char *us = (unsigned char *) s;
  while (*us) {  // Test for string's end.
    *us = islower(*us) ? toupper(*us) : tolower(*us);  // Swap  case.
    us++; // Advance pointer to next character.
  }
  return s;
}
```

---

**Test code**

- Use a local buffer.
- Best to test the return value of input functions to determine if input succeeded.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char line[100];
  printf("Bitte gebe deinen Satz ein: ");
  if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    printf("%s", TLG_swapcase(line));
  }
  return 0;  // Optional with main().
}
```